# Bind to dictionary with a dynamic key

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a toggle button in a DataGrid:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header=""   >
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>          
       <ToggleButton Checked="ToggleStrawSpecificTrue_Click" 
            Unchecked="ToggleStrawSpecificFalse_Click" Margin = "0,0,10,0"
            Width="150" HorizontalAlignment = "Center">
           <ToggleButton.Style>
               <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
               <Style.Triggers>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  Path=DataContext.IsSpecificDict[id]}" Value="false">
                       <Setter Property="Content" Value="{x:Static resx:IVFOocytes.NotPartOfGroup}"></Setter>
                   </DataTrigger>
                   <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding  Path=DataContext.IsSpecificDict[id]}" Value="true">
                       <Setter Property="Content" Value="{x:Static resx:IVFOocytes.PartOfGroup}"></Setter>
                   </DataTrigger>
                   </Style.Triggers>
               </Style>
           </ToggleButton.Style>
       </ToggleButton>
   </DataTemplate>
```

`IsSpecificDict` is a dictionary with `int` key and `bool` value, and it is a part of the VM:

```
private Dictionary<int,bool> _isSpecificDict;

public Dictionary<int,bool> IsSpecificDict
{
  get { return _isSpecificDict; }
  set { _isSpecificDict = value; OnNotifyPropertyChanged("IsSpecificDict");  }
}
```

The ItemSource of the DataGrid is a DataView. If I bind the DataTrigger to a column in the    DataView it works, but I need it to go to the dictionary because it is calculated. 
Is there a way to do this? The binding stuff is confusing.
Thanks

Comment: If it's in the `DataContext` then `DataContext` should not appear in the path. Your problem will be binding using the dynamic `id` index. Learn to debug bindings first, it's useful.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/356294/Using-path-parameters-when-binding-data-in-WPF). I am not completely sure but I think something like this `IsSpecificDict[id]` is not supported adhoc